# Prevent element from resizing when zoomed, other than using vh

Tags: css

I found the `vh` unit, and modified a site's style with a browser extension. It kind of worked, but the problem is that if I resize the browser window, it also affects the size. Is there anyway to prevent a specific element like `div` from changing its size, ever? Not ctrl + wheel zoom, and not even browser window resizing?

==== Below is the reason why I want to do it. You can skip it, if you are busy. ====

For some reason, web browsers do not provide a way to use smooth zoom (I am not sure about its technical term, but the zoom you get on Android or iOS) on a desktop OS without a touch screen or a trackpad. So, I have to use the traditional zoom (ctrl + wheel) which changes the page layout.

The problem is that, a lot of web sites now have a fixed thick toolbar at the top, and that thing gets stupidly large when I used ctrl + wheel to enlarge the small font of the content. So, I was looking for a way to kind of "freeze" the sizes of certain elements even when ctrl + wheel zoom is used. 
[image]

Comment: did you try using minmax() ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax

Comment: @FarazA. No, I never heard of it, but I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: It does not seem to work. The documentation page says it can only be used with something called "grid".